# Using Google API for Python- where do I get the client_secrets.json file from?

Tags: python, json, google-api

I am looking into using the Google API to allow users to create/ edit calendar entries in a company calendar (Google calendar) from within iCal.

I'm following the instructions at: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app

Step 2 says that I will need the application's `client ID` and `client secret`. I can see the `client ID` in the 'Credentials' page for my app, but I have no idea what the `client secret` is or where I get that from- anyone know what this is? How do I download it? Where can I get the value from to update the field?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[image: client_ids_tab.png]

Go to credentials tab. Client IDs will be listed there. In the right, there is an option to download it (`.json` file)

[image: downloadbutton.png]

Answer (score 24):

If you go to your [Google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) you should see a section titled **OAuth 2.0 client IDs**. Click on an entry in that list, and you will see a number of fields, including **Client secret**.

If you have not yet created credentials, click the **Create credentials** button, and follow the instructions to create new credentials, and then follow the steps outlined above to find the **Client secret**.

Comment: Thank you!  This should really be in the documentation.  https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive

Comment: This information is old and I am in search of the same information for the latest version of the Google developers console.

Comment: @GaneshMS Did you have any luck? I am in your same position.

Comment: for me, I create another credentials from the dropdown I chose 0Auth Client Id, and then the client secret pops up automatically

Comment: @JackZakiZakiulFahmiJailani is there any way to do this with Service Account?