# Google Drive API Upload Command ResponseBody always null C#

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, google-drive-api

I am working on a system powered by a Raspberry Pi. As part of this I am attempting to upload a text file to my google drive from the Pi. As a first test, I have a UWP app to create a text file of temperature and humidity data and try to upload it.

When it gets to the upload command, nothing happens. No exceptions are thrown but neither are any files uploaded. I have searched the web and followed lots of dead ends, but without an error I don't really know where to begin to find out why the file is not uploading; I have followed the instructions from Google and like I say, nothing throws an exception, it just doesn't work... Any suggestions would be really welcome as I have been spending a long time Googling for answers now and found nothing.

here is the meat of the code behind the xaml page of the uwp app (I can send you the whole project if you ask). I have not included a couple of the methods in the code below as it is only the method `StoreValues()` that is giving me gyp it the moment. This is the first iteration of the project that has not thrown an error.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
    static string AppName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";
    static string fileName = "Environmental_Data";
    static string fileExtension = ".txt";
    private const int DHTPIN = 4;
    private IDht dht = null;
    private GpioPin dhtPin = null;
    private DispatcherTimer sensorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private int counterWrite = 0;
    private int counterStore = 0;
    //the number on the end of the filename that will be incremented each time a file is produced.
    //TODO remove old files and reset counter periodically
    private int fileId = 1;
    //read values every this many seconds
    private int readInterval = 1;
    //write a new line to the file every this many readings
    private int writeCollectionSize = 2;
    //send file to cloud every this many lines
    private int storeCollectionSize = 4;

    private StorageFolder Folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    public List<Environment> Readings;
    public StorageFile File1;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeLocalFiles(fileId);
        InitializePi();
    }

    private async void InitializeLocalFiles(int fileId)
    {
        try
        {
            //make a new target file to save our data to
            var newFile = $"{fileName}_{fileId.ToString()}{fileExtension}";
            File1 = await Folder.CreateFileAsync(newFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            File1 = await Folder.GetFileAsync(newFile);
            //let a human know where the first file is
            Debug.WriteLine(File1.Path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("error incountered in InitializeLocalFiles: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void InitializePi()
    {
        try
        {
            //set up the pins etc
            dhtPin = GpioController.GetDefault().OpenPin(DHTPIN, GpioSharingMode.Exclusive);
            dht = new Dht11(dhtPin, GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

            //This is what the environment class looks like: public class Environment 
            //{ public decimal Temperature; public decimal Humidity; public DateTime DateTime; }
            Readings = new List<Environment>();
            sensorTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(readInterval);

            //add the tick to the clock and set it going
            sensorTimer.Tick += sensorTimer_Tick;
            sensorTimer.Start();

            //initialise the app
            temperatureMeter.Value = "OFF";
            humidityMeter.Value = "OFF";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("error incountered in InitialisePi: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void sensorTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        try
        {
            //every tick of the clock, we will read the sensor to get new values
            readSensor();

            //if we got to the end of the write collection, then it is time to aggregate the figures and write a line to the local file
            if (counterWrite == writeCollectionSize)
            {
                counterWrite = 0;
                Readings.AggregateListToCSV(File1);
                //clear the list of readings ready for the next tick
                Readings.Clear();
            }
            //if we got to the end of the store collection, it's time to send the local file on a trip around the world
            if (counterStore == storeCollectionSize)
            {
                counterStore = 0;
                StoreValues(File1);
                //rather than deleting the file, we will make a new one for the next go-round
                fileId += 1;
                InitializeLocalFiles(fileId);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("error incountered in sensorTimer_Tick: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private async void StoreValues(StorageFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            string cred = @"{""installed"":{""client_id"":""* **REDACTED FOR FORUM QUESTION ***"",""redirect_uris"":[""urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"",""http://localhost""]}}";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cred);

            //I'm using credentials stored in memory, but you could use a json file
            using (var stream =
                 //new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                 new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                //TODO find out why I have to copy the token.json file every time to the app folder - for some reason it does not copy over even though set to Copy Always
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            }

            //set up the stuff that the Google Drive seems to require. I don't pretend to understand this bit
            DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = AppName,
            });

            service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
                Name = "My Report",
                MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.file"
            };

            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;

            //using (var stream = new FileStream(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (var stream = File.Open(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "text/plain");
                request.Fields = "id";
                await request.UploadAsync();
            }
            //request.ResponsBody is always NULL - why??
            var responseFile = request.ResponseBody;
            //this line causes an error "attempted to read or write protected memory"
            if (responseFile == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"** ERROR **    File {fileName}_{(fileId - 1).ToString()}{fileExtension} could not be uploaded.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"File ID: {responseFile.Id.ToString()}");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("error incountered in StoreValues: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

this yields a Debug Output that looks like this (a snippet shown)

```
 ....
C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\e50d180b-3aea-4119-a4ff-72592c8ac7b5_4j4qdv46jwqvm\LocalState\Environmental_Data_6.txt
Lines ready to write: 1    |     Lines ready to store: 1
** ERROR **    File Environmental_Data_5.txt could not be uploaded.
Lines ready to write: 2    |     Lines ready to store: 2
18.9,10.0,2/16/2019 7:32:16 AM

Lines ready to write: 1    |     Lines ready to store: 3
Lines ready to write: 2    |     Lines ready to store: 4
18.9,9.9,2/16/2019 7:32:19 AM

C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\e50d180b-3aea-4119-a4ff-72592c8ac7b5_4j4qdv46jwqvm\LocalState\Environmental_Data_7.txt
** ERROR **    File Environmental_Data_6.txt could not be uploaded.
Lines ready to write: 1    |     Lines ready to store: 1
Lines ready to write: 2    |     Lines ready to store: 2
18.9,10.1,2/16/2019 7:32:22 AM

Lines ready to write: 1    |     Lines ready to store: 3
Lines ready to write: 2    |     Lines ready to store: 4
The thread 0xfac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Lines ready to write: 1    |     Lines ready to store: 1
18.9,10.05,2/16/2019 7:32:25 AM

C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\e50d180b-3aea-4119-a4ff-72592c8ac7b5_4j4qdv46jwqvm\LocalState\Environmental_Data_8.txt
** ERROR **    File Environmental_Data_7.txt could not be uploaded.
Lines ready to write: 2    |     Lines ready to store: 2
...
```

I believe I have all the credential etc in place - I have to copy the token.jsn file that was generated from my credentials onto the pi every time I deploy, but nonetheless it all seems to be connecting as it should.

While I'm beginning to get a bit of an understanding of the beginnings of wpf, this is all very much outside my ken and after 3 weeks of trying to sort this problem on and off, I'm really at the end of my tether - any suggestions would be brilliant.

Comment: In full disclosure, I'm eye-balling your code and too lazy to spin-up a repro of it. What happens if you replace `await request.UploadAsync();` with `request.Upload`?

Comment: The position of the message changes, but still no file appears on the Google Drive - I have seen that the `uploadasync()` sometimes does cause problems, but apparently here, that's not it.

Comment: Did you enable the Google Drive service in the Google project that you're authenticating against? I got off my lazy horse and repro'd your code and my subset works. https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/overview?project=[[YOUR-PROJECT-HERE]]

Comment: I can access my own Google Drive and I believe that is the account the app is looking at... Is that what you mean? In order to test whether files were added invisibly, I also wrote a script to list all the files that are on the drive using the same credential; the files listed are those I see in my browser, although still listed by that app after I deleted them in browser (oddly).

Comment: Your credentials file (`client_secret.json`) includes a reference to `project`. This `project` is the one that you're authenticating against. If you take that value (let's call it `${PROJECT}`) and replace it in the following URL, you should see "Google Drive API" listed: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=${PROJECT}`. However, it sounds as though you're able to query your Drive to list files but not upload a file. Is that correct? Here's my sample: https://gist.github.com/DazWilkin/9e7b0889f0b5ae93eb048c8fdf22fc0d

Comment: I am able to query but not upload. I'll do the things you suggest after work - very pleased to have something to do on this!

Comment: I didn't have the client_secret.json file; only credentials.json and token.json, but I found out how to get the file [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136699/) and then used it to look at the project - this is what I saw: [link](https://imgur.com/lmUWJ65) I think this looks like you describe. I just tried your code and have successfully uploaded an image from my PC. I have never had that browser security prompt from my app - maybe something to do with running it on the Raspberry Pi? I'll try to use what you gave on the Pi and see if I can make more progress.

Comment: Google provides various ways for you to authenticate against its services. The `client_secret.json` uses 3-legged auth: you the human clicking the link and auth'ing the app, your app and the Google service. This is probably what you want. Alternatively, you can use 2-legged auth using a service account. In this flow, you delegate permission to the service account to operate on your behalf, there's then no human|URL prompting.

Comment: @DazWilkin Did you got the solution? I am facing the same problem. I am integration in .net using c#

Comment: @XamDev see my Gist in the comment above as it includes working code.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for the reply. Just a question do we need client_secret.json file  OR credentials.json file ? These two are different ways of authentication?

Comment: @DazWilkin Can you please help me here. My response body is still coming null. I have tried exact your code ? Do I missing something ? I need this desperately actually

Comment: @DazWilkin Ok I got it.. There was not enough space on my drive.. Just quick question how can we upload file under shared with me folder ?

Comment: @XamDev It seems that you already determined that you want OAuth2 Client ID credentials. You can't upload files to the "shared with me" folder. This is a folder that represents the set of files that have been shared with you (by others).

Comment: Apologies for long absence - I have been trying different ideas as well as falling down a WireShark hole that led me nowhere (I wanted to check the request, but there is no ARM WireShark available and I have failed to look at the WLAN packages), investigating Google Backup and Sync (I wondered about letting that do the work but not possible) and trying to get other ideas. I think the impediment is the Pi itself; there is a wealth of code that works on PC. I will try asking the Pi community and get back here if any further answers. Any working solution will be posted here / marked as answer.